# Button and font looks low-res windows.h

Tags: c++, winapi

I am playing around with a simple C++ window and I created a button with `CreateWindowEx`, but when I compile and run, the button and its text has a very low resolution.

My button:

[image: ugly]

Windows Button:

[image: pretty]

Do I have to add something to my .manifest file? or my resource.rc file? I am pretty lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send a WM_SETFONT message to the control with the font you want it to use.

To get the proper font you call SystemParametersInfo with SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS to have it fill in a NONCLIENTMETRICS struct, then use CreateFontIndirect on the lfMessageFont member of the struct.

Also take a look at this function: [SetProcessDPIAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
I suspect DPI scaling is what is causing the button to look blurry.